# why 100% or 100vh height not occupying full page height

Tags: html, css

I was learning `css` pseudo-selector class `::before`. I am confused how come 100% value given to `height` property of `background-color` not actually occupying full page height. I tried with viewport height also. Same issue. Below is my code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

 :root {
  --navbar-height: 59px;
}

#navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

#navbar ul {
  display: flex;
}

#navbar::before {
  content: "";
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  /* height being 100% or 100vh not occupying full page */
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

#navbar ul li {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

#navbar ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 22px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li class="item"><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="#">services</a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="#">contactus</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**output**

[image]

what I expected was black `background-color` because have been given 100% height will occupy whole page. But it didn't happen. Why is it so?

Comment: The pseudo element probably inherits the `display:flex` from `#navbar::before`
and flex is overriding the height/width parameters. try adding `display:block` to `#navbar::before` or using `min-height` instead of `height`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is due to   display: flex; on  #navbar. Remove that and you should be fine. Another solution is wrapping the navbar in a parent div and adding :: before on it.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The `100vh` is actually working, but it gets centered, that's why you only see the bottom half.

Comment: Thanks Cristi. Yes, got your point. Some strange and need to learn behavior with flex-box.

Comment: Yes @Kokodoko you are right. I had to comment `align-items: center;` in `#navbar`

Answer (score 2):

Because your positioning is absolute you need to check the top and left properties.

I replicated your code and then opened the chrome dev tools as shown in the attached screenshot. If you open the computed tab you will see that the top property is -516.378px.

You can do this by clicking Elements>Computed which will show you all the properties after the browser has calculated them.

[image: chrome Devtools]

If you add top: 0; as shown below you can override the calculated css position.

```css
#navbar::before {
  content: "";
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  /* height being 100% or 100vh not occupying full page */
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

Here's a stackblitz example you can play with to try it out yourself:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-82vdk5?file=style.css

Comment: No problem, I wanted to add the computed part as I thought it was far more valuable than just giving you the answer. I wanted you to have the tools to diagnose some of those weird styling issues.

Comment: Actually when Cristi made her point, it immediately click my mind. Only I had to do was comment the `align-items: center;` while targeting `#navbar`

Comment: Ahh I see, this is why the height ended up being around -500px. Yeah, fair point Cristi Marian got straight to the cause of the offset.

Comment: Can you explain why the browser would, under reasonable assumptions, end up giving a negative margin of -516px to this element by default?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to position your `:before` correctly. Add below CSS to your `#navbar::before` and you should be set:

```
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

Comment: Actually I didn't wanted it to stretch to the bottom. I was just confused because of 100% height given and still it is half occupying. I was just curious to know why this behavior happening. I think @Cristi Marian answer satisfied my concern. Thanks a lot any way.